# Exchanging array between Fortran and C

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have the following C and Fortran code where I would like to exchange some data

```
FUNCTION exchange_data(data) bind(c,name='exchange_data')
    use iso_c_binding
    integer(kind=c_int)                                 :: exchange_data
    real(kind=c_double), intent(inout), dimension(*)    :: data

END FUNCTION exchange_data

....

WRITE(*,*), "Sent data to C"
DO I=1,NumBl
    DO J=1,WindSpeedCoordNr
        WRITE(*, FMT2), GLOBAL_COORD_ALONG_BEAM(I, J, :)
    END DO
END DO
cflag = exchange_data(GLOBAL_COORD_ALONG_BEAM)

WRITE(*,*), "Received data from C"
DO I=1,NumBl
    DO J=1,WindSpeedCoordNr
        WRITE(*, FMT2), GLOBAL_COORD_ALONG_BEAM(I, J, :)
    END DO
END DO
```

And the following test C code:

```
int exchange_data(double* positions)
{

    printf("Received data from Fortran");
    bladepositions = positions;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbld; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < datapointnr; j++) {
            printf("[");
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

                printf("%5.4f ", bladepositions[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i]);
                windspeedalongblade[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i] = 1.0;
            }
            printf("]\r\n");
        }
    }


    positions = windspeedalongblade;

    printf("Data will be send from C");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbld; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < datapointnr; j++) {
            printf("[");
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                printf("%5.4f ", positions[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i]);
            }
            printf("]\r\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This has the following output

```
Sent data to C
  -18.6593  -29.1175  137.0735
  -18.8588  -29.1308  137.0803
  -19.0582  -29.1441  137.0871

Received data from Fortran
[-18.6593 -29.1175 137.0735 ]
[-18.8588 -29.1308 137.0803 ]
[-19.0582 -29.1441 137.0871 ]

Data will be send from C
[1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 ]
[1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 ]
[1.0000 1.0000 1.0000 ]

Received data from C
  -18.6593  -29.1175  137.0735
  -18.8588  -29.1308  137.0803
  -19.0582  -29.1441  137.0871
```

I seems I can transfer data to the C function but not back to Fortran code. How can I achieve that?

Comment: To make sure I understand - is the problem that in the last printout ("Received data from C"), the values should be "1.0"?

Comment: Yes.  I expect that.

Comment: Here: `positions = windspeedalongblade;` you make `positions` point to somewhere else, probably some global location. That means that the data in the original `position`, the one the Fortran code knows about, isn't modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the following line:

```
positions = windspeedalongblade;
```

doesn't permanently assign `windspeedalongblade` to `positions` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) the difference between passing by value and by reference).

To do that you would need for positions to be passed as a pointer to the array:

```
int exchange_data(double** positions)
{
    ...
    *positions = windspeedalongblade;
    printf("Data will be send from C");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbld; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < datapointnr; j++) {
            printf("[");
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                printf("%5.4f ", *positions[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i]);
        }
            printf("]\r\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But in this case you have to be sure that `windspeedalongblade` remains persistent until you get to use `positions`.

The simpler solution is to leave the function as it is and assign the values of the `positions` array directly:

```
int exchange_data(double* positions)
{

    printf("Received data from Fortran");
    bladepositions = positions;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbld; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < datapointnr; j++) {
            printf("[");
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

                printf("%5.4f ", bladepositions[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i]);
                windspeedalongblade[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i] = positions[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i] = 1.0;
            }
            printf("]\r\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Data will be send from C");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbld; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < datapointnr; j++) {
            printf("[");
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                printf("%5.4f ", positions[3 * datapointnr * k + 3 * j + i]);
            }
            printf("]\r\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So in the end it depends whether you want `positions` to be an array or just a pointer to an array. From the looks of the Fortran code it seems that it is an array, in which case the second solution would be best.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, at the end I added a `memcpy`.

Comment: @OHLÁLÁ if the entire array must be copied, yes that is an efficient solution